# Почему не работает find_by после связи has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

В экшене `show` нахожу пост:

```
@post = policy_scope(Post).find(params[:id])
```

Там же нахожу одну главную категорию:

```
@category = @post.categories.actual
```

`actual` выглядит следующим образом:

```
scope :actual, (-> { find_by(actual: true) })
```

Этот код работает правильно лишь в одном случае - когда существует категория с флагом `actual`.

Если все категории поста носят в себе `actual` равный `false`, то `find_by(actual: true)` ни на что не повлияет и пользователь получит список всех категорий этого поста.

Также я заменил `actual` на `find_by(actual: true)` и все заработало. То есть проблема конкретно в реализации через `scope`.

И раз проблема была в `scope`, то я заменил его на это:

```
def self.actual
    find_by(actual: true)
end
```

И этот вариант работает.

Далее заменяю на этот вариант:

```
scope :actual, (-> { where(actual: true) })
```

Возвращается мне `[]`, то есть все верно. Но как только после `where` прописываю `take` или `first`, то получаю снова все категории.

Почему это происходит?

*P.S. В данный момент `policy_scope` примитивный и имеет в себе либо `scope.all`, либо `scope.all.where(published: true)`. В данном примере `scope.all`.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `where` возвращает объект `ActiveRecord_Relation`, к которому вы можете применять методы ActiveRecord, метод `Enumerable#take` возвращет массив, а `ActiveRecord::FinderMethods#find_by` — объект модели. Возвращать из `scope`, что-то отличное от `ActiveRecord_Relation` неправильно, так как вы не можете дальше пользоваться полученным объектом в цепочке вызовов, как это происходит с другими методами ActiveRecord. Считается, что создавая такие `scope`-ы, вы запутываете коллег по проекту.

Comment: tl;dr: этот `actual` должен быть не скоупом, а методом.

Comment: Да, согласен, именно так.